# Is it possible to play in flash player a smooth streaming video hosted on the iis7?

Tags: silverlight, flash, iis-7, smooth-streaming-player

I want to play smooth streaming video from IIS using the flash video player like e.g. jw flash player instead of silverlight player?
Which video format should I use in this case? Can flash then play e.g a video via smooth streming  encoded with microsoft encoder?
Do you know some alternative video players, that combines flash and silverlight functionality (selected per java script) to use with flash and silverlight?

Comment: any chance you got anywhere on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 player does not support playback of the *.ism files (IIS Smooth Streaming format).
This plugin can probably help you for playback in flash player: [Microsoft Smooth Streaming Plugin for OSMF](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36057)

Answer (score 0):

Why not go with the HTML5 video player?

Comment: Not all of our customers have a browser compatible with html 5.